# Why does Rspec/Factory Girl generate objects with nil ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

This is my test in question:

```
  it "should return all relatives of a specific relation - e.g. 'sister'" do
    u1 = create(:user)
    ft = create(:family_tree, user: u1)
    relation = "sister"
    u2 = create(:user)
    ft2 = create(:family_tree, user: u2)
    membership = create(:membership, invited: u2, relation: relation, invited: u1, family_tree: ft)
    expect(u1.relatives(relation).first.user.email).to eq u2.email
  end
```

These are the respective factories:

**User**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users (truncated for brevity)
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string(255)      default("")

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    association :family_tree
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password123"
    password_confirmation "password123"
  end
end
```

**Family Tree**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: family_trees
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :family_tree do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
  end
end
```

**Membership**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: memberships
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  family_tree_id          :integer
#  user_id                 :integer
#  relation                :string(255)
#  member_id               :integer
#  invited_id              :integer

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :membership do
    family_tree
    association :inviter, factory: :user
    association :invited, factory: :user
    relation { Faker::Lorem.word }
    member
  end
end
```

But when I run the test, I get objects returned with `id=nil`.

```
[7] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> u1
=> #<User id: nil, email: "sage.tromp@dubuquehauck.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$JfWM7TvH9CgQWdGDXXy9L.5Y7TmhNFacrImOxYHnzt/...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", first_name: "Rowland", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:47", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "velit", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Aut qui non aut occaecati. Consequuntur eveniet do...", last_name: "Johnson", gender: 1>
[8] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> ft
=> #<FamilyTree id: nil, name: "Jadyn Volkman MD", user_id: 906, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49">
[9] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> relation
=> "sister"
[10] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> u2
=> #<User id: nil, email: "samantha.breitenberg@simonis.net", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$gtcqmNDq4NhuyvAZsZNrg.GxoBzOkiVbfANpdcLYSLD...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", first_name: "Noah", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:47", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "unde", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Omnis sit asperiores aut. Iste omnis accusantium i...", last_name: "Pagac", gender: 1>
[11] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> ft2
=> #<FamilyTree id: nil, name: "Bridie Lang", user_id: 907, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49">
[12] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership
=> #<Membership id: 111, family_tree_id: 1220, user_id: 908, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", relation: "sister", member_id: 129, connection_sent_at: nil, connection_responded_at: nil, connect_send_limit: nil, connect_times_sent: nil, connected: nil, connect_type: nil, request_status: nil, connection_removed_at: nil, invited_id: 906>
```

Notice though that the associations seem to work still, even if it returns a record with an object of `id=nil`, as you can see here:

```
[13] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership.inviter
    => #<User id: nil, email: "nils.walter@bruen.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$RAbEyhoU/cvJu1lvDM0mNOb2.VSoCnR76qThkbjWJNU...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", first_name: "Alyce", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:47", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "placeat", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Autem vitae aliquid dicta doloribus rerum atque. H...", last_name: "Metz", gender: 1>
[14] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership.invited
=> #<User id: nil, email: "sage.tromp@dubuquehauck.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$JfWM7TvH9CgQWdGDXXy9L.5Y7TmhNFacrImOxYHnzt/...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", updated_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:49", first_name: "Rowland", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 19:31:47", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "velit", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Aut qui non aut occaecati. Consequuntur eveniet do...", last_name: "Johnson", gender: 1>
```

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

This is my `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'capybara/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include SpecAuthentication, type: :controller
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

This is my `spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Comment: How exactly do you create your objects in your tests? Seems like you're using `build_stubbed()`

Comment: I am using `create(:user)` - which is a FactoryGirl creation alias - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories

Comment: Sounds like a failing validation

Comment: @FrederickCheung -- hrmm...good idea. How would I know what is failing if it fails silently? How can I force it to whine to tell me what the issue is?

Comment: @FrederickCheung It doesn't seem to be the validations, because I have this same problem on models that have no validations at all.

Comment: in pry try calling, say `u1.save!` and see what happens. In fact (note: not knowing FactoryGirl real well) I'd try adding a bang to `create!` to see if that works+helps

Comment: @TarynEast - So the weird thing is, when I call `u1.save!` at the command line in PRY...that saves the record and shows me the ID for the `u1` object. However, when I use `create!` it throws an error. `create(:user)` is supposed to save the record. If I want to just instantiate it, but not save it, I would use `build(:user)`. So that's what is confusing me.

Comment: Are there validation preventing them to save? I think it works because you are using transaction as your cleaning strategy, if you switch it to truncation, it probably will fail. You can add an after_rollback to your models and print some debug messages to see if they actually got rolledback. Also, check if any of your callback methods are returning false by mistake. Any callbacks returning exactly false will halt the callback chain.

Comment: You might want `deletion` for your `js: true` strategy. See [Suspenders' defaults](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/blob/master/templates/database_cleaner_rspec.rb). I agree with the others that I suspect a validation error. Can you share your model files? At least the validation portions?

Comment: It also looks like there's two `invited` keys in your `membership` factory instance: `create(:membership, invited: u2, relation: relation, invited: u1,` and no `inviter` key.

Comment: I'm having what might be a similar issue, only it's leaving all fields as nil IF AND ONLY IF I have a paperclip has_attached_file association....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615501/factory-girl-creating-test-objects-with-null-created-at-value-only-with-papercli

Answer (score 4):

If you build object using FactoryGirl it instantiates new model without id since you haven't provided id definition in your factory.

When you are creating new model FactoryGirl persists this model into database and #id field would be generated by your database.

So if you don't want to persist factories, you should provide #id attribute definition:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:id) { |number| number } 
    association :family_tree
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password123"
    password_confirmation "password123"
  end
end
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I don't specify an `id` attribute in the Factory Definition of another class `membership` and it assigns an ID successfully. Why would it do that there and not the other classes/models? See the definitions in the question above.